# Qual è il significato di "corsa" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, il pittore Orazio Gentileschi dice queste parole:

> «Ho finito a Monte Cavallo, non voglio più lavorare a Roma, mi bisogna viaggiare. Per ora si va a Firenze, il Granduca m'ha fatto parlare, le condizioni convengono. C'entra anche una **corsa** a Pisa.»

Ho letto tutte le [accezioni del vocabolo "corsa" sul Vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/corsa/), ma non riesco a capire quale sia il suo significato nel brano precedente. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: Fra parentesi, “Monte Cavallo” è più conosciuto come “Quirinale”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ho finito a Monte Cavallo, non voglio più lavorare a Roma, *mi bisogna viaggiare*:

quest'ultima frase suggerisce che l'accezione in cui è utilizzato il termine *corsa* è quella della voce n°2 del vocabolario [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/corsa/):

> Per estens., **il percorso di un mezzo pubblico di locomozione** (treno, tram, autobus, ecc.): *partire con la prima c.; arrivare con l’ultima c.; conservare il biglietto per tutta la durata della corsa;* anche il tragitto che si compie con una vettura di piazza: *combinare il prezzo della corsa*.

Un termine utilizzato più frequentemente in quest'accezione è *[tappa](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tappa_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/)*, nel senso di parte di viaggio compresa fra due soste. Inoltre, come l'utente @mario fa notare sotto, l'espressione più comune per una situazione simile è *fare un [salto](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/salto.shtml) a*, nel senso di «compiere una breve visita o una rapida puntata».

Comment: Cioè, sarebbe un viaggio a Pisa prima di arrivare a Firenze?

Comment: @Charo Credo si tratti di questo ed il termine sarebbe utilizzato come sinonimo di *tappa*.

Comment: Perchè prima? Io capisco che pensi che, durante la permanenza a Firenze, avrà anche il tempo di una corsa (a/r) a Pisa. Non sono sicuro della sinonimia con _tappa_.

Comment: @mario hai ragione: non c'è assolutamente nulla che faccia pensare che vada a Pisa *prima* di arrivare a Firenze e non *dopo*. Non so perché anch'io ho pensato così, in maniera del tutto arbitraria. Quanto al significato del termine, intendevo *fare tappa a...* come *fare un salto a...*.

Comment: @mrnld :-), _fare tappa_ mi risuona come una tappa in un viaggio, diverso da _fare un salto_, che collego a una deviazione.

Comment: @mario Tra i significati di *[tappa](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tappa/)*, però, c'è anche quello di "fermata intermedia più o meno breve". In ogni caso "fare un salto a..." sembra anche a me più appropriato, ma al momento della stesura della risposta non mi era venuto in mente. Grazie per la segnalazione! :)

Comment: @mrnld Ma _breve fermata intermedia_ nel viaggio tra Roma e Firenze non è una salto a Pisa, che semmai sarà da compiersi  dopo l'arrivo a e durante la permanenza a Firenze. Nel caso del brano, siccome la condizioni convengono, ci sarà appunto anche tempo e modo, arrivati a Firenze, di fare una corsa a Pisa. :-)

Comment: @mario Non colgo la differenza...

Comment: @mrnld anche perchè da Roma a Firenze non si passa/passava per Pisa :-)

Comment: @mario Ahimè, devo contraddirti riguardo alla [situazione corrente](https://goo.gl/photos/yyfvkb5Ahm8hw3Uz9). Quanto al passato, se uno si muoveva in carrozza (come credo avvenisse nel racconto), non era molto soggetto ai vincoli delle linee ferroviarie. :)

Comment: @mrnld uhm, uhm! Ma sembra che Firenze sia tappa intermedia tra Roma e Pisa, non Pisa tra Roma e Firenze, o no?

Comment: @mario Certo, se "prenotava" il treno per Firenze non sarebbe arrivata "per caso" a Pisa. Resta però dubbio lo spostamento in treno e con Trenitalia (tra le altre cose sarebbe arrivata oggi partendo allora, dati i ritardi accumulati...).

Comment: Secondo Viamichelin, Rm-Fi-Pi sono 358km, Rm-Pi-Fi sono 411km; percorso più breve, con le strade esistenti oggi. Però va anche tenuto conto che al tempo dei Gentileschi non c'erano gallerie e varianti di valico, e anche se ci fossero state i cavalli vanno più veloci in piano che in salita. Quindi non mi sento di escludere che fare il grosso della strada sulla costa avrebbe potuto davvero essere più veloce.

Answer (score 0):

La "corsa a Pisa" può anche essere soltanto "un salto a Pisa". Parlando di un nuovo lavoro, potrebbe anche significare che potrà fare "ogni tanto un salto a Pisa". Con mezzi pubblici o privati. In Toscana "fo una corsa a Empoli" vuol dire andarci, anche col proprio mezzo di trasporto.